# Android duplicate registration id for different devices

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am seeing this issue on my push notifications server - different Android devices (identified by their IMEI) receive the SAME registration id from Google's GCM service.
Isn't the registration id supposed to be unique? at east for the same application or GCM API Key?

I saw this thread but there doesn't seem to be an answer there:
[Can two different devices have same GCM Registration ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685755/can-two-different-devices-have-same-gcm-registration-id)

Any help would be much appreciated

**EDIT**
here is the relevant code for registration:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(
                                   "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
                   intent.setPackage("com.google.android.gsf");
                   intent.putExtra("app",
                                   PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(), 0));

                   intent.putExtra("sender", flatSenderIds);
                   context.startService(intent);
```

Comment: Are both devices virtual, physical or a mix?

Comment: All the devices are physical real devices

Comment: Could you include the snippet where you register against GCM service and how you test the obtained ID?

Comment: which helper library are you using ? What are you doing when the device is unregistered Can you post the code ?

Answer (score 6):

The only idea that comes to my mind is that this deprecated method will assign the same ID on different devices if the extra value for `sender` is the same on all of them. That differs from the current version where you don't say who you are, you don't even send an `Intent`, you just call `register()` and Google determines who you are and what ID you should be given.

If you finally use this new library, there's an example snippet of how to register (inside an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread`):

```
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = null;

try {
  // Will be for the first time
  if (gcm == null)
    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(your_context);

  // Registration against the GCM service
  String regid = gcm.register(YOUR_SENDER_ID_OBTAINED_FROM_YOUR_PROJECT);

  // You'll need to send the registration info to your remote server
  registerRemoteServer(regid);

  Log.d("MyGCM", "Registered on GCM as " + regid);
}
catch (final IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: nKn- here you also use the Sender Id in gcm.register(YOUR_SENDER_ID_OBTAINED_FROM_YOUR_PROJECT);don't think this is the issus

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes Google changes the registration ID and you'll have multiple IDs associated. The server that sends the notification (your server) has to update the database with the new ID.

For more info check this document:

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html

they says:

**It's an Canonical IDs**

> On the server side, as long as the application is behaving well,
>   everything should work normally. However, if a bug in the application
>   triggers multiple registrations for the same device, it can be hard to
>   reconcile state and you might end up with duplicate messages.
>
> GCM provides a facility called "canonical registration IDs" to easily
>   recover from these situations. A canonical registration ID is defined
>   to be the ID of the last registration requested by your application.
>   This is the ID that the server should use when sending messages to the
>   device.
>
> If later on you try to send a message using a different registration
>   ID, GCM will process the request as usual, but it will include the
>   canonical registration ID in the registration_id field of the
>   response. Make sure to replace the registration ID stored in your
>   server with this canonical ID, as eventually the ID you're using will
>   stop working.

Comment: Thanks - but that's not the case for me. I see that totally DIFFERENT devices are receiving the SAME registration id from GCM, and I have verified that it is not a server side issue

Answer (score 2):

Well, after adding your registration code, I can see you are using the old method of registration. That method has been depecated since the middle of last year. It is likely to be less reliable than the new registration method.

You should try registering via the `GoogleCloudMessaging.register` method of the Google Play Services library. That's the recommended way by Google. See the official demo [here](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/DemoActivity.java).

Comment: Thanks Eran. But using the play services lib forces the device to have Google play services, and if we give the library to a developer it will also force him to include the play services library project in his project... I still don't understand why is it acceptable that Google will provide the same registration ids to different devices. Event if this API is deprecated there are many apps that still use it